# SMB Filesharing on Windows CE 6

Tags: windows-ce, smb

I'm attempting to configure an SMB file sharing server on a Windows CE 6 device.

My initial attempts have mostly been with the desktop version of NK.exe.
When I start, SMB0: is running as smbserver.dll

I've set (hopefully) suitable registry values, and then re-started the SMBServer process:

services refresh SMB0:

However, I never see the service advertised when I attempt to attach an SMB client (for example, by looking for file shares in desktop windows, or attempting to connect an SMB client to the IP address of the WinCE device.

I wonder if it's necessary for the SMB registry settings to be available at boot time? My devices is NOT using a hive-based registry, so the registry settings aren't available a boot time. I'd hoped that refreshing the SMB server process would be enough to get file sharing going. That way, I can just set the registry values programatically in my application program, restart the SMB service, and not have to rebuild the kiosk NK.exe (the kiosk NK.exe seems to include the smbserver.dll - it was built by a not very competent third party, and the tools to rebuild it go back to Visual Studio 2005. It would be "interesting" to rebuild NK.exe).

Do I need to rebuild the OS to use a hive-based registry?

Any ideas?

My registry settings are all under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:

```
            Ident\Name "aName"
            Ident\Desc, "A string"
            Ident\OrigName "Another string"

            \Services\Smbserver\SMB\Shares\VirtualRoot\Type Dword:0         
            \Services\Smbserver\SMB\Shares\VirtualRoot\Path "a valid path"
            \Services\Smbserver\SMB\Shares\VirtualRoot\UserList "*"

            \Services\Smbserver\AdapterList "*"
            \Services\Smbserver\Keep DWord:0
            \Services\Smbserver\Prefix "SMB"
            \Services\Smbserver\Index  DWord: 0

            \Services\Smbserver\SHARES\UseAuthentication DWord:0L
```

As you can see, I've temporarily turned authentication off - I'm hoping to start by getting this to work in the CE desktop environment, and then add authentication, and getting it to work in the kiosk environment.

I'd be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say you need to set `"Keep"=dword:1` as per the [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms884924.aspx):

> **Keep** Default set to 1. If this is set to zero (0), the DLL will be
>   unloaded immediately after initialization.

The SMB server does not require a hive-based registry. We've used it on multiple projects with only a RAM-based registy.

For reference, these are the registry settings we use on CE 7 to expose the root folder as `\\<IP address>\Root`:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services\SMBServer\Shares\Root]
    "Path"=""
    "Type"=dword:0

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services\SMBServer]
    "AdapterList"="*"
    "Keep"=dword:1
    "Prefix"="SMB"
    "Index"=dword:0
    "DLL"="smbserver.dll"
    "Order"=dword:12

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services\Smbserver\Shares]
    "UseAuthentication"=dword:0
    "NoSecurity"=dword:1
```

Comment: Nice catch on the value for Keep! I had thought that I'd set it to 1, but I was wrong.

Comment: I do see the service as running, both before and after the refresh. I'm glad to know that the SMB server can run with a RAM-based registry! I'll run a test with Keep set to 1, and keep my fingers crossed. Thanks!

Comment: I just did an experiment.<newline> I set the registry values using a local registry editor on the WinCE device (this time, I set Keep to 1).<newline>Then I issued "services refresh SMB0:" <newline> I'm still missing something though, as I still don't see the device as an SMB server.<newline>So I'm still confused. Thank for your reply though!

Comment: Is is possible that I've missed a vital step?        
What I've done is simply to set values in the registry, 
and then refresh the SMB0: service. 
Is there more to it than that?        
Thanks!

Comment: In my experience advertising the server rarely works reliably, but if everything is set up correctly you should be able to at least connect to the CE device by typing `\\<IP address>` in a desktop Explorer. Are you able to connect to the device this way?

Comment: Thanks for the caution about the server not advertising! Unfortunately though, I can't connect that way. I can ping the device, but that's about it.

Comment: I can configure a share using the Windows CE Remote Management Tool, so at least I know that the device is capable of creating an SMB file server. So, my guess is that either my registry settings are wrong, or that I'm not restarting the SMB server process correctly.

Comment: I've also discovered that, at least when using the Remote Management Tool, filesharing doesn't work unless a user other than ADMIN has been created (even if the permissions for the share are set to "*").

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the registry settings we use (albeit on CE 7). Another thing you could try is dump the registry contents before and after using the Remote Management Tool and compare.

Comment: To answer your previous comment, no there shouldn't be more to it than modifying the registry and refresh the service. However, it appears the SMB server sources are not included with Platform Builder so I am unable to verify this, all I can say is that is how it _should_ work. On our platforms we modify the registry very early in the start-up process, i.e. before the SMB service is loaded, so we've never had a need to refresh the service.

Comment: Thanks so much for your patient help! After double-checking the registry settings (thanks for posting yours) and refreshing the service, I see the SMB service, but am unable to connect. This appears to be because there is a bug in CE6 involving unauthenticated access (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.windowsce.embedded/44M_EGDv3nA). So I need to add a user programmatically, which it appears may not be possible for an normal application. At least, that's my current thought.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the linked article - it does say there was a bug in CE 5.0 and 6.0, but it also says that CE 6.0 has since been fixed. We actually use the SMB server with unauthenticated access on CE 5.0 as well, and I can confirm it works there too (I just tried).

Comment: I've re-read the entire chain of comments again to be sure, and I believe that Bussmann's final comment acknowledges that CE6 file sharing doesn't actually work when authentication is disabled - he says that he couldn't access the shares from another (XP) machine until he turned authentication on, at which point he could see the share.  I've carefully verified that I am setting the registry keys in the same way that you do, and that I've restarted the SMB server. However, when I attempt to mount the share on another computer, I cannot connect as guest, and the CE machine has no users.

Comment: Oddly, if I start by connecting to the device with the remote management console, and add users, and then make the appropriate registry settings, I still cannot access the share. I always get authentication failures, even though I'm using one of the just-created users. When I re-check the registry settings they are "correct" (ie: they are what I imagine they should be). This leaves me frustrated and confused.

Comment: I've added the registry settings to the project_reg file, so that they will be in effect at boot time. That isn't doing the trick though. I'm also trying to figure out how to set a default password, using the Local Authentication sub-system, in an attempt to get file sharing to work with a pre-defined user (assuming that unauthenticated SMB file sharing really doesn't work). I have got Telnet working, but SMB and FTP are still not authenticating (although I wonder if this might be masking a more fundamental problem!).

Comment: Sorry, not sure what to suggest then :-( I assume your Platform Builder installation is fully up to date with all QFE's. If you are able to use the kernel debugger on your target hardware you could see if any interesting traces are printed

Comment: I finally started over with a fresh install of everything, including the BSP, drivers, etc. When I did that, I was able to create an unauthenticated share. Thanks so much for all of your help!

Comment: Thanks Andromeda, that's great to hear!

Answer (score 3):

There's another issue at play here, which is that the Windows CE 6 SMB server default to using NTLM ver 1. Windows 7 and above, by default, require NTLM version 2.

In order for your Windows 7+ system to see the SMB share, it's necessary to modify the security policy:

On Windows 7, run secpol.msc, find Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options. Look for LAN Manager Authentication Level, and set it to 'Send NTLM response only’